# Comparing return values from two overloaded methods in an if statement (in main method)

Tags: java

So i'm new to java, we just started this language in my programming class about a month ago. Anyhow, we're on overloading methods right now (just started methods last week) and I'm having trouble with comparing the values of the return statements in the overloaded methods. My intention is to compare them in an if statement in the main method. I'm sure the answer is simple, but i can't find information on it in my textbook or online. Sorry about the sloppy indentation, I'm having trouble with the features on this website and it's the first time i've used it. would appreciate any help! Here is the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pizzaCalculation {
       public static void main(String[] args){
           //create scanner
           Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
           //create sentinel while loop, initiate priceperinch for both pizzas
           int sentinel = 1;
           //create while loop
           while(sentinel != 0){

               //create input for round pizza
               System.out.println("What is the price of the round pizza?");
               double priceRound = i.nextDouble();
               System.out.println("What is the radius?");
               double radius = i.nextDouble();
               pizzaPrice(radius, priceRound);

               System.out.println("What is the price of the rectangular pizza?");
               double priceRect = i.nextDouble();
               System.out.println("What is the width and length of the rectangular pizza?");
               double width = i.nextDouble();
               double length = i.nextDouble();
               pizzaPrice();

               //create if statement to determine best deal
               if (pricePerInchRound > pricePerInchRect){
                   System.out.println("The best deal is the round pizza which is $"+pricePerInchRound);
               }else{
                   System.out.println("The best deal is the rectangular pizza is $"+pricePerInchRect);
               }

               //ask if user would like to do again
               System.out.println("Would you like to do another calculation? Enter 1 for yes and 0 for no.");
               sentinel = i.nextInt();
           }
        }

        public static double pizzaPrice(double num1, double priceRound){
            Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
            //this is for round pizza
            double areaRound = Math.PI * num1 * num1;
            double pricePerInchRound = priceRound / areaRound;
           return pricePerInchRound;
        }

        public static double pizzaPrice(double num1, double num2, double priceRect){
            //this is for rectangular pizza
            //create scanner
            Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
            double areaRect = num1 * num2;
            double pricePerInchRect = priceRect / areaRect;
            return pricePerInchRect;
        }
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I'm trying to compare the values of pricePerInchRound and pricePerInchRect from the two overloaded methods in the main method. I need to find out which value is smaller, so I can tell the user which is the better deal. I intend to do that with an if statement. I've tried initializing the variables in the main method, but it didn't help.

Comment: To call methods you must add the parenthesis to them like `pricePerInchRound()`

Comment: And, if they have any arguments, you must add the arguments between the parenthesis

Comment: I've tried calling it as well, but it's still giving me errors.                                           
`if (pizzaPrice() > pizzaPrice()){
                System.out.println("The best deal is the round pizza which is $"+pricePerInchRound);
            }else{
                System.out.println("The best deal is the rectangular pizza which is $"+pricePerInchRect);
            }`

Comment: Judging by the fact that one of the methods was done correctly, and you missed the exact same step a little bit later. My guess is that this is someone else's code, and they didn't give you the complete version.

Comment: While I understand that assumption, I was stuck on this program for around 4 hours and was honestly trying whatever i could to fix this code. This is 100% mine. I did not copy, the only reason it looks like this is because, as i said, we just started learning about methods this week, and my professor isn't the best at teaching so i'm having to learn from the book. And all of my methods are correct, i was having trouble figuring out how to compare the values in an If statement, that I've now fixed thanks to a helpful comment from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

So there are several issues:

1. You need to pass parameters to the second call of `pizzaPrice()` like this

   `pizzaPrice(width, length, priceRect);`
2. You need to store results of method calls in variables like

   `pricePerInchRound = pizzaPrice(a, b);`

   `pricePerInchRect = pizzaPrice(a, b, c);`

Comment: Thank you so much! I seriously appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `pizzaPrice()` but you need to store the resulting value in a variable so you can use it later (and pass the right parameters).

```
double pricePerInchRound = pizzaPrice(radius, priceRound);
```

and ...

```
double pricePerInchRect = pizzaPrice(width, length, priceRect);
```

Also, take care to name your method parameters better - num1, num2 aren't very descriptive. You could have used width, length.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help. Also, i did originally have it named 'width' and 'length', but my professor is very picky about variables and suggested that I change it? Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: Here's your argument against the professor: The biggest cost in software development is maintenance. Imagine you are asked to maintain the code years after the original developer has left. What variable names would you prefer to see to help you understand what the code does.

Comment: You're right! I try my best generally to give good variable names, and I'll try to polish my ability on that further in the future. My professor is just not the best at my university. About half my class is failing and he's one of the lowest rated professors in our district, so I have to learn a lot of our material through the textbook and online. I really appreciate your help though; my programs finally working and I understand how to call values now!

Comment: If you want to learn more, there are web sites such as hackerrank.com (plus many others) that provide problems you can solve. They usually have a healthy community forum to assist with the solutions when you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you for that! I'll definitely be using that as a resource!